# Mysql Isn't starting

Tags: arch-linux, mysql, xampp

I recently asked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243876/gparted-says-disk-is-full-but-it-isnt) the reason mysql wasn't starting is because there was no disk space. After a long discussion with casey in chat room and after following his answer, I freed about 10 GB and restarted Manjaro.

Tried again, mysql isn't staring still, Xampp log

```
2015-11-18 14:30:00 925 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'key_buffer' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'key_buffer_size' instead.
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [Note] /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.8-MariaDB) starting as process 1148 ...
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [ERROR] mysqld: Error writing file '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/aria_log_control' (Errcode: 28 "No space left on device")
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Can't create file' when trying to use aria control file '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/aria_log_control'
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ib_logfile101 size to 5 MB
2015-11-18 14:30:00 7f17827b1740 InnoDB: Error: Write to file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ib_logfile101 failed at offset 0.
InnoDB: 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 0 were written.
InnoDB: Operating system error number 28.
InnoDB: Check that your OS and file system support files of this size.
InnoDB: Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
InnoDB: Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot set log file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ib_logfile101 to size 5 MB
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2015-11-18 14:30:00 139738950080320 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-11-18 14:30:00 925 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/manjaro.pid ended
2015-11-18 14:30:46 1343 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
2015-11-18 14:30:46 139913878849344 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'key_buffer' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'key_buffer_size' instead.
2015-11-18 14:30:46 139913878849344 [Note] /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.8-MariaDB) starting as process 1488 ...
2015-11-18 14:30:46 139913878849344 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Size of control file is smaller than expected' when trying to use aria control file '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/aria_log_control'
2015-11-18 14:30:46 139913878849344 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2015-11-18 14:30:46 139913878849344 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-11-18 14:30:47 139913878849344 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-18 14:30:47 139913878849344 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-18 14:30:47 139913878849344 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-11-18 14:30:47 139913878849344 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-18 14:30:47 139913878849344 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed ta2015-11-18 14:30:47 1343 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/manjaro.pid ended
2015-11-18 14:57:55 3043 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'key_buffer' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'key_buffer_size' instead.
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [Note] /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.8-MariaDB) starting as process 3187 ...
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Size of control file is smaller than expected' when trying to use aria control file '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/aria_log_control'
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ib_logfile101 size to 5 MB
2015-11-18 14:57:55 7fe526c60740 InnoDB: Error: Write to file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ib_logfile101 failed at offset 0.
InnoDB: 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 0 were written.
InnoDB: Operating system error number 28.
InnoDB: Check that your OS and file system support files of this size.
InnoDB: Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
InnoDB: Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot set log file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ib_logfile101 to size 5 MB
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2015-11-18 14:57:55 140622174750528 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-11-18 14:57:55 3043 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/manjaro.pid ended
2015-11-18 15:01:34 4077 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
2015-11-18 15:01:34 140046011664192 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'key_buffer' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'key_buffer_size' instead.
2015-11-18 15:01:34 140046011664192 [Note] /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.8-MariaDB) starting as process 4221 ...
2015-11-18 15:01:34 140046011664192 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Size of control file is smaller than expected' when trying to use aria control file '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/aria_log_control'
2015-11-18 15:01:34 140046011664192 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2015-11-18 15:01:34 140046011664192 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-11-18 15:01:34 140046011664192 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-18 15:01:34 140046011664192 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-18 15:01:34 140046011664192 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-11-18 15:01:34 140046011664192 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-18 15:01:34 140046011664192 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
20152015-11-18 15:01:34 4077 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/manjaro.pid ended
2015-11-18 15:52:43 9982 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'key_buffer' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'key_buffer_size' instead.
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [Note] /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.8-MariaDB) starting as process 10126 ...
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Size of control file is smaller than expected' when trying to use aria control file '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/aria_log_control'
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ib_logfile101 size to 5 MB
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ib_logfile101 to /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ib_logfile0
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=1624742
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1625100
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621417961216 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [ERROR] Aria engine is not enabled or did not start. The Aria engine must be enabled to continue as mysqld was configured with --with-aria-tmp-tables
2015-11-18 15:52:43 139621725980480 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-11-18 15:52:45 9982 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/manjaro.pid ended
2015-11-18 18:27:50 14725 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
2015-11-18 18:27:50 139984820520768 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'key_buffer' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'key_buffer_size' instead.
2015-11-18 18:27:50 139984820520768 [Note] /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.8-MariaDB) starting as process 14869 ...
2015-11-18 18:27:50 139984820520768 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Size of control file is smaller than expected' when trying to use aria control file '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/aria_log_control'
2015-11-18 18:27:50 139984820520768 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2015-11-18 18:27:50 139984820520768 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-11-18 18:27:51 139984820520768 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-18 18:27:51 139984820520768 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-18 18:27:51 139984820520768 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-11-18 18:27:51 139984820520768 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-18 18:27:51 139984820520768 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2015-11-18 18:27:51 139984820520768 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-18 18:27:51 139984820520768 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-11-18 18:27:51 139984820520768 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-18 18:27:51 139984820520768 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-11-18 18:27:51 139984820520768 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-11-18 18:27:51 139984820520768 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-11-18 18:27:51 139984820520768 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1625110
2015-11-18 18:27:51 139984443004672 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2015-11-18 18:27:51 139984820520768 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2015-11-18 18:27:51 139984820520768 [ERROR] Aria engine is not enabled or did not start. The Aria engine must be enabled to continue as mysqld was configured with --with-aria-tmp-tables
2015-11-18 18:27:51 139984820520768 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-11-18 18:27:53 14725 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/manjaro.pid ended
2015-11-18 18:36:36 15587 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'key_buffer' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'key_buffer_size' instead.
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [Note] /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.8-MariaDB) starting as process 15731 ...
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Size of control file is smaller than expected' when trying to use aria control file '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/aria_log_control'
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1625120
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555589760768 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [ERROR] Aria engine is not enabled or did not start. The Aria engine must be enabled to continue as mysqld was configured with --with-aria-tmp-tables
2015-11-18 18:36:36 140555972851520 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-11-18 18:36:38 15587 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/manjaro.pid ended
2015-11-18 18:43:14 1844 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
2015-11-18 18:43:14 140577518511936 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'key_buffer' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'key_buffer_size' instead.
2015-11-18 18:43:14 140577518511936 [Note] /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.8-MariaDB) starting as process 1990 ...
2015-11-18 18:43:16 140577518511936 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Size of control file is smaller than expected' when trying to use aria control file '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/aria_log_control'
2015-11-18 18:43:16 140577518511936 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2015-11-18 18:43:16 140577518511936 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-11-18 18:43:16 140577518511936 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-18 18:43:16 140577518511936 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-18 18:43:16 140577518511936 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-11-18 18:43:16 140577518511936 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-18 18:43:16 140577518511936 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2015-11-18 18:43:16 140577518511936 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-18 18:43:16 140577518511936 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-11-18 18:43:16 140577518511936 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-18 18:43:17 140577518511936 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-11-18 18:43:18 140577518511936 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-11-18 18:43:18 140577518511936 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-11-18 18:43:18 140577518511936 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1625130
2015-11-18 18:43:19 140577140098816 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2015-11-18 18:43:19 140577518511936 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2015-11-18 18:43:19 140577518511936 [ERROR] Aria engine is not enabled or did not start. The Aria engine must be enabled to continue as mysqld was configured with --with-aria-tmp-tables
2015-11-18 18:43:19 140577518511936 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-11-18 18:43:20 1844 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/manjaro.pid ended
2015-11-18 18:45:43 2298 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'key_buffer' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'key_buffer_size' instead.
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [Note] /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.8-MariaDB) starting as process 2442 ...
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Size of control file is smaller than expected' when trying to use aria control file '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/aria_log_control'
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1625140
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140531900331776 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [ERROR] Aria engine is not enabled or did not start. The Aria engine must be enabled to continue as mysqld was configured with --with-aria-tmp-tables
2015-11-18 18:45:44 140532279383872 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-11-18 18:45:46 2298 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/manjaro.pid ended
2015-11-18 21:22:43 6960 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
2015-11-18 21:22:43 139779123144512 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'key_buffer' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'key_buffer_size' instead.
2015-11-18 21:22:43 139779123144512 [Note] /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.8-MariaDB) starting as process 7104 ...
2015-11-18 21:22:43 139779123144512 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Size of control file is smaller than expected' when trying to use aria control file '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/aria_log_control'
2015-11-18 21:22:43 139779123144512 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2015-11-18 21:22:43 139779123144512 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-11-18 21:22:43 139779123144512 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-18 21:22:43 139779123144512 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-18 21:22:43 139779123144512 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-11-18 21:22:43 139779123144512 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-18 21:22:43 139779123144512 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2015-11-18 21:22:43 139779123144512 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-18 21:22:43 139779123144512 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-11-18 21:22:43 139779123144512 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-18 21:22:43 139779123144512 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-11-18 21:22:43 139779123144512 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-11-18 21:22:43 139779123144512 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-11-18 21:22:44 139779123144512 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1625150
2015-11-18 21:22:44 139778745943808 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2015-11-18 21:22:44 139779123144512 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2015-11-18 21:22:44 139779123144512 [ERROR] Aria engine is not enabled or did not start. The Aria engine must be enabled to continue as mysqld was configured with --with-aria-tmp-tables
2015-11-18 21:22:44 139779123144512 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-11-18 21:22:46 6960 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/manjaro.pid ended
```

Comment: try to move /opt/lampp/var/mysql/aria_log_control out of the way (do not delete it just in case), and restart mysql

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro worked worked!! please answer so i can vote it up and accept, and I can delete that file now right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it is a corrupt /opt/lampp/var/mysql/aria_log_control from the logs.

Please move out of the way (do not delete it just in case), and restart mysql.

If it works, please delete the old copy.

Comment: One last comment, it is better to avoid filling up the disk often, or moving logs to partitions where they are alone. Corruption of unrelated files and databases due to lack of space can often arise when the applications try to (re)write them without having space for them. I also understand novices using xammp or lammp in Linux, however hopefully you will grow out of them when more experienced.

Comment: true, i will keep an eye on that from now on, i'm originally i debian and ubuntu user, where apt-get tells you to autoremove and autoclean, pacman doesn't so got filled with 10 gb of junk files and i had no idea, although i know about pacman -Sc, but didnt know that that directory is causing problems. Now will keep running that command on a regular basis